# How to bury an invisible mark into lines of text?

Tags: grep, text, byte

How can I bury an **invisible** mark into random lines of text? Such a mark has to be there, though it will be invisible to someone reading that text printed out on the console.

I want to identify those lines by means of an invisible mark in order to, for instance, grep them in or out later.

I tried `0x00` without success. I expected `grep` to print lines matching `0x00` somewhere. But this didn't work:

```
$ echo -e "a\0b" | hexdump -C
00000000  61 00 62 0a                                       |a.b.|
00000004
$ echo -e "a\0b" | grep "a\0b"
```

Comment: My thesis was on steganography in text data; rather than paste all of it I'll simply say "it's a difficult problem with multiple tradeoffs".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no fully reliable way to put an invisible mark in a text file. A text file has no room for anything that isn't plain text, after all. Comments (text that doesn't belong in the main text) are a form of markup.

Null bytes are a bad idea not only because they may be rendered as `^@` or `␀` or `�` or other ways, but also because many text processing tools choke on them. Null bytes are an end-of-string marker in the [C programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) and many programs treat it as the end of a text chunk (e.g. of a line, but not necessarily) because they're written in C or use libraries written in C.

If your text is encoded in Unicode, you can use one of its several zero-width characters:

- U+200B [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (a zero-width breaking space)
- U+200C [ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) (a zero-width word constituent that prevents ligatures)
- U+200D [ZERO WIDTH JOINER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) (a zero-width word constituent that forces ligatures)
- U+2060 WORD JOINER (a zero-width non-breaking space)

The spaces are not word constituents, the others are. Although none of these characters are visibly rendered (assuming a viewer with reasonable Unicode support), this has an impact when selecting text, moving around, searching, etc. The breaking space can be rendered as a line break.

Comment: Another trick is Unicode characters that look like Latin characters. The interesting thing is that what fools humans is easily spotted by software, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can `grep` for null or other special characters using the `-P` flag and the hex code:

```
echo -e "a\0b\nhello" | grep -a -P '\x0'
```

You could also hide text by putting backspace characters after them, for example:

```
$ echo -e "the matrix\0\0\0\0\n\bh\ba\bs\b \by\bo\bu\b\0\0:-)"
the matrix
:-)

$ echo -e "the matrix\0\0\0\0\n\bh\ba\bs\b \by\bo\bu\b\0\0:-)"  | hexdump -C
00000000  74 68 65 20 6d 61 74 72  69 78 00 00 00 00 0a 08  |the matrix......|
00000010  68 08 61 08 73 08 20 08  79 08 6f 08 75 08 00 00  |h.a.s. .y.o.u...|
00000020  3a 2d 29 0a                                       |:-).|
00000024
```

Comment: Backspace characters only work when displaying text directly in a terminal or with some terminal-based programs. It doesn't work in most of the tools people use to view text files (editors, browsers).